# Accidental question, deleted, now unable to post again

Tags: discussion, support, edits, deleted-questions, rate-limiting

I was in the process of writing up a question for the main Stack Overflow site, when I accidentally [posted the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30873061/1726609) by hitting enter while trying to add some tags.

I immediately deleted the question, since I didn't want it to show up on the site yet - I wasn't finished. I noticed the "delete" link turned into "undelete", so I tried editing the question before undeleting it again, which unfortunately isn't possible.

I'm now finding myself in the position of not being able to post the finished question due to my previous accidental submission:

> You can only post once every 90 minutes.

I just wanted to report this issue and include as much information as possible (including what I tried to fix the situation); the question is not anything that'll prevent me from working on my project.

Comment: Type up your edits in notepad or similiar, _then_ undelete and click edit. Copy/paste in your edits to the question. Done. Or, since it sounds like you've completed the question, just take your completed question, undelete your accidental post, and edit it with your completed question.

Comment: I removed the [bug] tag - the delay is to prevent spammers spamming spam.  I cant recall why a low rep user cant edit a deleted post of their own - there is a reason though.

Comment: The not being able to edit a deleted question part is _also_ by-design. It's to keep OPs from deleting an unanswered question, editing it to be a completely different question, then undeleting it. (If I remember that correctly.)

Comment: ^^^ thats the reason

Comment: @Plutonix So pressing enter in the tag selection is *supposed* to post the question?

Comment: @copygirl: What else should pressing enter in the tag-field do? Honest curiosity, because I don't have a clue... (Yes, it's unfortunate when one expects it to do something else.)

Comment: @Deduplicator Auto-complete / insert the currently selected tag?

Comment: Technically pressing enter inside of any of a form's input fields will submit the form. I haven't ever heard of someone accidentally submitting using enter like that before though. I wonder if that happens often.

Comment: @copygirl Most sites I've been to, tab is the "auto-complete" key, not enter. Most software I've used as well.

Comment: @Kendra Just like tab is used to auto-complete in this case, whereas its default behavior is to select the next element in the form, I think enter should be used to finish the selection instead of the default behavior - submitting the form.

Comment: Then make a feature-request out of it. But be sure to outline why you think this would be a major improvement and why the devs should spend time on it. Be prepared for disagreement- And keep in mind that on Meta, downvotes can signal disagreement. (Also, and most importantly, _be sure to search for duplicates first._ I don't think that suggestion has come up before, but check anyways to be sure.)

Comment: @Kendra Considering I'm already finding people disagreeing with me, I don't think it's worth pursuing this myself.